# ESP32 usb to STM32 USB cdc mode - USB to USB

Tags: usb, stm32, esp32

I have an STM32 with a USB interface that can be connected to a PC and recognised as a CDC device, all working good.

Now I would like to connect an ESP32 board to this STM32 device using USB to USB.
How can I program USB device type on the ESP32 so that can talk and be recognised by the STM32?

ESP32 would act as a wifi scanner and send/communicate data to the STM32 board that doesn't have wifi capabilities.

Any ideas or info very much appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to be USB? Because then you wont be abled to connect your PC to your STM32 anymore afaik. Normally one would use one of the typical IC to IC interfaces like I2C or SPI for such a connection.

Comment: You are absolute right, but I can not access or modify the hardware itself, it has to be a plug in external module.

Answer (score 0):

STM32 has to be the HOST device. Many STM32 µConstrollers have OTG USB peripheral with HOST device capabilities.

You need to implement the HOST device stack.

Comment: Thanks PJ, do you know if I will be able to switch between USB Device and Host mode automatically? Do you know of some example project or resource in order to do this? Thanks